# How to point Google Apps subdomain to external websites?

Tags: domains, redirects, cpanel, google-workspace

I have registered for a domain in Google Apps. It is automatically registered with GoDaddy.
I was wondering how can I make a subdomain point to my blog:

`blog.example.com` => `myname.blogspot.com`

`photo.example.com` => `flickr.com/photos/mystream/`

How can this be done?

I can access the zone file editor (DNS Manager) in `godaddy.com` but I am not sure if I need to change the *Cname/A* records for this.

Comment: are you using windows or linux setup on godaddy? Do you want to redirect the subdomains to end up at blogspot & flickr? I know you can only setup a custom domain within blogspot, but the setup is different for the windows and linux setups within godaddy.

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy calls the feature that you are looking for "domain forwarding".  Here is [the GoDaddy help document about domain forwarding](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name). It states:

> In the Domain Manager, you can add subdomains and forward them to URLs. You can also edit or delete forwarded subdomains.
>
> Subdomains are extensions of your domain name that you can forward to URLs or point to IP addresses and directories in your hosting account. For example, if your domain name is example.com, you can add subdomain.example.com and point it to a specific website in a subdirectory of your hosting account.